# Thief: Beauty Within quest: how to enter the building for the quest?

Tags: ps3, thief

I just started playing Thief on the PS3 and got the quest *Beauty Within* to steal the hand mirror for Basso.  The map shows the target in Stonemarket, in a building beside the clock tower, and I've found a window on the back side of that building which I assume is the way in for the quest.  However, I can't find a way to reach that window.  There is a "rafter" that juts out beneath the window, which you obviously must jump onto somehow, however the rooftop pathways and ledges in the area don't take you near enough to jump onto it.  So that makes me think you must have to drop down from the rooftops above, and I can't find a way to them.

I've attached a photo of the map showing my location at the window as the arrow, and the objective as the circle just above me to the right, inside the building.

Any tips for getting into the building for this quest?!

[image: Thief - Beauty Within Quest - how to enter this building?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it.  The window I mentioned is actually where you *exit* the quest.  The entrance is a window that you access after using a rope arrow to reach the rooftop from Clock Tower Plaza.  The first photo below is the location where I'm sitting on the rooftop next to the window (after completing the quest, so the quest marker no longer appears).  The second photo is me in the same location, turned around with my back to the window so you can see the rope I used to reach the rooftop from the plaza.

[image: Rooftop window map location.]
[image: Rope used to reach the rooftop.]